# What is the best solution to get the best combination of a sum in between two parameters in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simple algorithm to achieve the best combination of values based on two params in an `array` of `objects`.

The whole code draft is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/volumetrics-kd9h5?file=/src/App.js)

First I have an `array` holding `objects`, the items which will be analyzed and packed into volumes together. All of the values are in `percentages`.

```
const nonStackableItems = [
    {
      id: 0,
      m2: 15,
      m3: 11,
      weight: 20
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      m2: 25,
      m3: 12,
      weight: 42
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      m2: 50,
      m3: 13,
      weight: 40
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      m2: 65,
      m3: 14,
      weight: 25
    }
  ];
```

This is the piece of code that does the calculations:

The idea is to combine these objects into packages, respecting the `maximum` of `100%` for each value (except for `m3` in this case, as all the packages should have enough `height` in this first analysis).

So the approach that I gave is just not good enough, as I am sorting this `array` by `m2` then by `weight`, call the `function` and then compare the length of both, and then choose the result that creates less volumes.

```
function nSVolHelper(arr, vol, param1, param2) {
    let newVol = {
      id: vol.length,
      m2: 0,
      m3: 0,
      weight: 0
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const validation =
        newVol[param1] + arr[i][param1] < 100 &&
        newVol.m2 + arr[i][param2] < 100;
      if (validation) {
        newVol.m2 += arr[i].m2;
        newVol.m3 += arr[i].m3;
        newVol.weight += arr[i].weight;
      }
      if (!validation) {
        return nSVolHelper(arr.slice(i), [...vol, newVol], param1, param2);
      }
    }
    vol.push(newVol);
    return vol;
  }

  function nSVol(arr, param1, param2) {
    return nSVolHelper(arr, [], param1, param2);
  }
```

I would like to find a way of doing this without taking as a base the order of the `array`, to get the finest calculation without running unnecessary code, without having to run the code ordering the arrays separately, then comparing them. This is not getting the best combination.

As an example, for better understanding:

If I pass the array sorted by `weight` I get a create 2 volumes.

```
console.log(
    "call",
    nSVol(
      nonStackableItems.sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight),
      "weight",
      "m2"
    )
```

If I pass this same `array` sorted by `m2` I get 3 volumes.

```
console.log(
    "call",
    nSVol(
      nonStackableItems.sort((a, b) => a.m2 - b.m2),
      "weight",
      "m2"
    )
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Cheers

Comment: "Another way of thinking..." Specifically?

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: My question is about the need of a solution that is not being achieved with my code. This is not just about reviewing, it's about a piece of code that is not doing what is required to. Don't you think this suits stackoverflow ?

Comment: probably easier using reduce tbh

Comment: I thought ```for``` was a lighter method @DenisTsoi. I was using ```reduce``` at the beginning. But this is not the focus of the question here

Comment: map/filter/sort can be chained together - as part of functional programming - 
logically its easier for the reader to understand the logic flow